# Pandoc --bibliography with Chicago Fullnote Bibliography missing space between contributors and title in citation

Tags: latex, pandoc, bibliography, citations

When using Pandoc for my citations (`pandoc -o FileOut.tex FileIn.md -S --bibliography=Primary.bib --csl=chicago-fullnote-bibliography.csl`) there is no space produced between the author (or contributors) and the title within a footnote. The spaces are correct in the bibliography. Any ideas?

Example:

```
@Roudinesco2008
```

produces this citation in a footnote

```
Elisabeth Roudinesco\emph{Philosophy
  in Turbulent Times: Canguilhem, Sartre, Foucault, Althusser, Deleuze,
  Derrida}, trans. William McCuaig (New York: Columbia University Press,
  2008).
```

but correctly generates this entry in a bibliography

```
Roudinesco, Elisabeth. \emph{Philosophy in Turbulent Times: Canguilhem,
Sartre, Foucault, Althusser, Deleuze, Derrida}. Translated by William
McCuaig. New York: Columbia University Press, 2008.
```

The `.bib` entry is as follows:

```
@book{Roudinesco2008,
    location = {New York},
    title = {Philosophy in turbulent times: Canguilhem, Sartre, Foucault, Althusser, Deleuze, Derrida},
    isbn = {9780231143004},
    url = {},
    shorttitle = {Philosophy in turbulent times},
    pagetotal = {184},
    publisher = {Columbia University Press},
    author = {Roudinesco, Elisabeth},
    translator = {McCuaig, William},
    date = {2008},
    keywords = {20th century, Education, Higher, France, History, Philosophers, Philosophy, Philosophy, French}
}
```

I'm pretty sure it's not a problem with my csl file, which is directly from the git repository. Maybe citeproc?

Any help is much appreciated.